# align inner div in vertical, horizontal center against the parent div without line breaking for the following span text element

Tags: css

If I didn't make parent container be  `inline-block` style

The inner arrow will be aligned in the center position which is I expected.
However, there will be a line-break for the following text.

[image: inline]

If I make the parent container be `inline-block` style

[image: inline]

## HTML

```
    <div class="queue-view-entry-line" name="Name">
        <div class="mycompany-document" style="/* display: inline-block; */">
            <div class="arrow-right">
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="entry-label">File Name</span><span class="entry-value"><a href="/mycompany/servlet/servlet.    FileDownload?file=00P41000007XUEEEA4" target="_blank">Planned Payment Dates 2017</a>
        </span>

    </div>
```

## CSS rules

```
div{
  .mycompany-document{
    background: #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    left: 64px;
    top: 64px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;

    .arrow-right{
      margin: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display:inline-block;
      width: 0.4em;
      height: 0.4em;
      border-right: 0.2em solid black;
      border-top: 0.2em solid black;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Where's the html? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The codes inserted looks nothing like the image. If there are more codes can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you give flexbox a try. It will quickly be your best friend!
I didn't feel like wrestling with your HTML, so I created a new example to show how you could achieve the desired effect.

Check out this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/omucfbzh/

```
   <div class="box">
      <h2>Documents</h2>
      <div class="others">
        <div class="arrow-container">
          <div> > </div>
        </div>
        <p>Planned Payment Dates 2017</p>
      </div>
    </div>


.box {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 7.5px;
}

.others {
  display: flex;
}

.arrow-container {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I will try it soon and get back to u